# Coded UI Application Under Test

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Just started implementing a coded ui test automation solution but keep running into an issue when starting the application.

The application seems to start just fine but no matter what I always get an exception stating:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException: "The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reasons:
1) Another instance of the application is already running and only one instance can be running at a time.
2) The application started another process and has now stopped. You may need to launch the process directly.
3) You do not have sufficient privileges for this application."

The application is a little strange as it currently is setup to run off of a setup.exe so the user always has the latest version.

Am I missing something in my code (sample below)? Or does the application need to be better set up before I start writing the automation tests. EXE is located in a network location.

```
ApplicationUnderTest aut = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"\\test.com\\applicationdir\\testenv\\application\\setup.exe");

WpfEdit userName = new WpfEdit(aut);
userName.SearchProperties.Add(WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "PART_UserName");

userName.Text = "TEST";
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-).
Would you be so kind to add some more information to you post, e.g. what steps have you already taken to identify the source of your problem.
You state you run the application from a network location. Does it help running it on you local machine? As VS starts your program, do you start VS as admin? Does the problem persist when running your test from the build files. What do you mean with that it runs of a setup.exe? Does your test needs to install the app first, before running the app's exe?

Comment: It doesn't work when running on my local machine and I start my VS as admin. Not really sure how to run test from the build files but will look into that.

Comment: The application is a click once application if that helps.

Comment: With build files I meant the bin\debug or bin\release folder. When you build your program in debug or release mode, your code gets compiled and the resulting files are found  in those folders. I test the program I need to test by storing the exe path (in release folder) in a config file, making the CUIT type it in a "run" window and starting the exe.

Comment: I Have no experience with ClickOnce apps, but found on the wiki page about ClickOnce that it uses Code Access Security (CAS). You could check if that causes any trouble. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security

Comment: Thanks for the help. Currently using a workaround where I start the app via Process and then pass it to the application under test FromProcess(). Seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using a workaround where I start the app via Process and then pass it to the application under test FromProcess(). Seemed to fix the issue.

Probably not the best solution and have to use a Thread.Sleep() but it works for now.

Example:

var process = Process.Start(@"pathToApplication");

Thread.Sleep(2000);

process = Process.GetProcessesByName("process.Name")[0];

ApplicationUnderTest aut = ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess(process);

Comment: Your test will fail when the process doesn't exist within 2 seconds.
A more graceful way of waiting for your app to be started would be by using a while loop with a timeout. You could use one of the functions from the `Process` class to check if the process exists in your current list of processes. That way, your code will continue as soon as the process is started, or fail if your timeout is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Used a while loop and it is much more stable now.